# Debugging LESS with less.js and @media -sass-debug-info in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css, less

According to http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-debugging, I can enable

```
<script>
    less = {
        dumpLineNumbers: "mediaquery"
    };
</script>
```

and debug less in Chrome or Firefox dev-tools/firebug, but I don't see any connection between the CSS properties and the LESS files in the Chrome dev tools with this option enabled. I do get additional @media info in the generated `<style>` tag but Chrome seems to just ignore it. eg:

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/http\:\/\/localhost\/web-project\/client\/style\/global\/global\.less}line{font-family:\000031}}
body {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
}
```

I know I can compile LESS before runtime (using node.js compiler) and enable `source-map` but I like to debug using the client parser for less - less.js.

What am I missing so I can debug less this way?

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports this debugging format at all. And Firefox requires [FireLss](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireless/) add-on. In other words it seems to be a good time to change your development workflow to something like `grunt-contrib-(less/watch/connect)` and use source-maps (everybody are about abandoning `-sass-debug-info` very soon).

Comment: [sass-sleuth-](http://www.mobify.com/blog/sass-sleuth-debugging-sass-in-webkit-browsers/) reads the `@media -sass-debug-info` in Chrome or Firefox, it possibly also works with Less? (buy me a mac and i will test it or you)

Answer (score 0):

http://q42.nl/blog/post/35203391115/debug-sass-and-less-in-webkit-inspector-and-save-css-cha describes that the development version of Chrome 24 did offer experimental support for a while. I expect that Chrome dropped support right after that.

The only working option seems to use FireLess together with Firebug in Firefox. How to use FireLess with Less v2 can be read at: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/fireless-less-v2/

As already mentioned also sass-sleuth did offer support in the past.